# Show image by order if item has active class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

```js
$(function() {
    $('.item').click(function() {
       $('.item').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    
    if ( $(".item:nth-child(1)").hasClass("active") ) {
    $(".opt-img:nth-child(1)").addClass("show");
    } 
    
    if ( $(".item:nth-child(2)").hasClass("active") ) {
    $(".opt-img:nth-child(2)").addClass("show");
    }
    
    if ( $(".item:nth-child(3)").hasClass("active") ) {
    $(".opt-img:nth-child(3)").addClass("show");
    }
    
    if ( $(".item:nth-child(4)").hasClass("active") ) {
    $(".opt-img:nth-child(4)").addClass("show");
    }
    
    if ( $(".item:nth-child(5)").hasClass("active") ) {
    $(".opt-img:nth-child(5)").addClass("show");
    }
            
});
```

```css
.item{
  width: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;  
  cursor: pointer;
}
.opt-img {
  display: none;
}
.show{
  display: block;
}
.active{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="operator-acc">
          <div class="item active">1</div>
          <div class="item">2</div>
          <div class="item">3</div>
          <div class="item">4</div>
          <div class="item">5</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="opt-imgs">
          <div class="opt-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/00f/fff.png"></div>
          <div class="opt-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/04f/fff.png"></div>
          <div class="opt-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/40f/fff.png"></div>
          <div class="opt-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/00e/fff.png"></div>
          <div class="opt-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f/fff.png"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If first .item class has .active class, add .show class to first .opt-img class. If second .item class has .acive class, add .show to second .opt-img class and also for third, forth and fifth item.

For now it's working only for the first item. And not working for other items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, I use the `eq()` method to determine the index of the image index, and the `index()` method to determine the index of the pressed button, which makes the logic code short.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.item').click(function() {
       $('.item').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
       
       $('.opt-img').removeClass('show');
       $('.opt-img').eq($(this).index()).addClass('show');
    });           
});
```

```css
.item{
  width: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;  
  cursor: pointer;
}
.opt-img {
  display: none;
}
.show{
  display: block;
}
.active{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="operator-acc">
          <div class="item active">1</div>
          <div class="item">2</div>
          <div class="item">3</div>
          <div class="item">4</div>
          <div class="item">5</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="opt-imgs">
          <div class="opt-img show"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/00f/fff.png"></div>
          <div class="opt-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/04f/fff.png"></div>
          <div class="opt-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/40f/fff.png"></div>
          <div class="opt-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/00e/fff.png"></div>
          <div class="opt-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f/fff.png"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be wrong but the click function should also have all the if statements, otherwise it will only work when the page is loaded like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.item').click(function() {
       $('.item').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
       checkActives();
    });
    function checkActives(){
      if ( $(".item:nth-child(1)").hasClass("active") ) {
        $(".opt-img:nth-child(1)").addClass("show");
      } 
    
      if ( $(".item:nth-child(2)").hasClass("active") ) {
        $(".opt-img:nth-child(2)").addClass("show");
      }
    
      if ( $(".item:nth-child(3)").hasClass("active") ) {
        $(".opt-img:nth-child(3)").addClass("show");
      }
    
      if ( $(".item:nth-child(4)").hasClass("active") ) {
        $(".opt-img:nth-child(4)").addClass("show");
      }
    
      if ( $(".item:nth-child(5)").hasClass("active") ) {
        $(".opt-img:nth-child(5)").addClass("show");
      }
    }
    checkActives();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I will just fix your code (without optimizing it) just to show the error.

Take a look at your code here:

```
    $('.item').click(function() {
       $('.item').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
    }); // <-------------- this must be moved to the end of you `$(function() {...})`
```

So the example is below. Some notes: I've added some CSS just for beautify (under the word `TEST`, you can remove it):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.item').click(function() {
    $('.item').removeClass('active');
    $(".opt-img").removeClass('show');
    
    $(this).addClass('active');

    if ($(".item:nth-child(1)").hasClass("active")) {
      $(".opt-img:nth-child(1)").addClass("show");
    }

    if ($(".item:nth-child(2)").hasClass("active")) {
      $(".opt-img:nth-child(2)").addClass("show");
    }

    if ($(".item:nth-child(3)").hasClass("active")) {
      $(".opt-img:nth-child(3)").addClass("show");
    }

    if ($(".item:nth-child(4)").hasClass("active")) {
      $(".opt-img:nth-child(4)").addClass("show");
    }

    if ($(".item:nth-child(5)").hasClass("active")) {
      $(".opt-img:nth-child(5)").addClass("show");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.item {
  width: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.opt-img {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}


/*TEST*/

.operator-acc {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="operator-acc">
      <div class="item active">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="item">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="opt-imgs">
      <div class="opt-img show"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/00f/fff.png"></div>
      <div class="opt-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/04f/fff.png"></div>
      <div class="opt-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/40f/fff.png"></div>
      <div class="opt-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/00e/fff.png"></div>
      <div class="opt-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f/fff.png"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```